# Longest Consecutive Sequence in Array C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have to create a function that will find the longest consecutive sequence of integers in an array.

The array is this:

`{1,2,3,4,4,4,5,7,9,10}`

Note: repeated numbers in a sequence are skipped.

Here is my code:

```
int longestSequence(const int arr[], int size)
{
  int currentSeq = 1;//set to 1 because all sequences are at least 1
  int maxSeq;

  for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
  {
    if (arr[i] == arr[i-1]);//skip repeated numbers

    else if (arr[i-1] == (arr[i] - 1))//check if index is 1 greater than last
    {
      currentSeq++;
    }
    else //if not reset and hold last sequence value as max
      {
        maxSeq = currentSeq;
        currentSeq = 1;
      }
  }
  if (currentSeq > maxSeq) //if the last index of the array was last in the sequence
  {
    maxSeq = currentSeq;
  }

  return maxSeq;
}
```

My code keeps returning 2 for this array but obviously it should be 5.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You always set `maxSeq` at the end of a sequence. You checj if if's actually longer for the last one outside the loop.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thank you for the response, however, even after moving it into the loop it still returns 2.

Comment: No you have to add a condition to the `else` to check if the current sequence is longer than the max. You'll also need to initialize `maxSeq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 sequences in your array:

- 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5 which has 5 consecutive numbers.
- 5, 7 which is not consecutive and will return 1.
- 7, 9 which will also return one.
- 9, 10 which has 2 consecutives and will return two.

In your loop you're doing this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] == arr[i-1]);//skip repeated numbers

    else if (arr[i-1] == (arr[i] - 1))//check if index is 1 greater than last
    {
        currentSeq++;
    }
    else //if not reset and hold last sequence value as max
    {
        maxSeq = currentSeq; // <-- You're resetting your maxSequence even if
                             // currentSeq is smaller.
        currentSeq = 1;
    }
}
```

Change your loop as following:

```
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] == arr[i-1])
        continue; //It is a good practice to skip the rest of the loop's 
                  //checks if you already know you're not gonna need them.
                  //The continue keyword skips only the current iteration of 
                  //the loop and improves intent readability.
    else if (arr[i-1] == (arr[i] - 1))//check if index is 1 greater than last
    {
        currentSeq++;
    }
    else //if not reset and hold last sequence value as max
    {
        currentSeq = 1; //This line stays.
                        //You only want to reset it under these specific conditions.
    }

    if (currentSeq > maxSeq) // Now you'll get the last sequence as well.
        maxSeq = currentSeq;
}
```

You can remove that check outside of the loop and go straight to the return. The last `currentSeq` will be properly registred if it is bigger than `maxSeq`.

Also, when I did this change I got a compile error because the new `if (currentSeq > maxSeq)` inside the loop tries to read `maxSeq` before it is ever set. So change the declaration of `maxSeq` to `int maxSeq = 0`.

With these changes I got the expected value of 5.

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer. I made the changes and got the expected output. I totally overlooked that I was overwriting `maxSeq` even when it was greater than `currentSeq`.

Comment: I found that the check outside the loop is needed in cases like this array: `{0,1,3,4,5,7,10,11,12,13}` since `maxSeq` will not update to 4 since the sequence was not broken before exiting the loop. so the code returned `3`.

Comment: @EdsellJ You are correct. Now I overlooked it haha. It is unideal to repeat code. I'll update my answer in a way that you only ever have to check and set `maxSeq` once.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void Log(int idx, int currentSeq, int maxSeq) {
  printf("current[%d] = %d, max[%d] = %d\n", idx, currentSeq, idx, maxSeq);
}

int LongestSequence(int* arr, int size) {
  int currentSeq = 1;
  int maxSeq = 1;  // max should be initialized as well
  Log(0, currentSeq, maxSeq);

  for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == arr[i - 1]) {
    } else if (arr[i - 1] == (arr[i] - 1)) {
      currentSeq++;
    } else {
      currentSeq = 1;
    }
    // maxSeq should be updated in time, otherwise it would be tossed away
    maxSeq = std::max(maxSeq, currentSeq);
    Log(i, currentSeq, maxSeq);
  }

  return maxSeq;
}

int main() {
  int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10};
  std::cout << LongestSequence(arr, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
current[0] = 1, max[0] = 1
current[1] = 2, max[1] = 2
current[2] = 3, max[2] = 3
current[3] = 4, max[3] = 4
current[4] = 4, max[4] = 4
current[5] = 4, max[5] = 4
current[6] = 5, max[6] = 5
current[7] = 1, max[7] = 5
current[8] = 1, max[8] = 5
current[9] = 2, max[9] = 5
5
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my brain does not know what you did there since I am a novice to `<vectors>` and have never used `<map>`

Comment: @EdsellJ you are so cute. I haven't used `vector` and `map` in the code. So don't worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

By running your program in a debugger with the sample array you provided, I determined that the variable `currentSeq` does indeed reach the value 5 and this value 5 is correctly written to `maxSeq`. However, later in the program, maxSeq gets overwritten by the value 1 and then 2.

Before overwriting `maxSeq`, you must determine whether it already contains a higher value than `currentSeq`. You already do this in one case, when you have reached the end of the array. But you don't do this in the other case.

For such a comparison to work, you must also initialize `maxSeq`, not just `currentSeq`. Otherwise, `maxSeq` may contain a very large number and always be larger than `currentSeq`.